# How to obtain parent template binding values in a nested binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout template like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="list">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="{text: name}"></li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

That I use like this:

```
<div data-bind="
  template: {name: 'list', data: itemList}, 
  myBinding: {itemType: 'foo'}
"></div>
```

I have a `myBinding` custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var bindingValue = valueAccessor();

    alert ( bindingValue.itemType );  // alerts "foo"

    // now set up a jQuery click handler
    $(element).on("click", "li", listItemClickHandler);
  }
};
```

And an event handler:

```
function listItemClickHandler() {
  var bindingContext = ko.contextFor(this);

  alert( "bindingValue.itemType ???" );
});
```

**Is there a way to get the `itemType` of the parent template, as provided in the custom binding, in the click handler though knockout's `bindingContext`?**

- Without adding some bogus CSS class like `.type-foo` to the `<ul>` (that's what I do now).
- Without storing `"foo"` in the array item during `myBinding.init()`.
- Without in-lining the event handler to take advantage of the closure variable (`bindingValue`).
- Without using jQuery's `event.data` facility. I could do that, but I'd like to retrieve it from knockout's binding context, unless that's impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binding context is passed in as the 5th argument to a binding.  So, you can augment that the binding context in your custom binding like `context.$itemType = bindingValue.itemType;`.  Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/yeN8P/

Another option is to ensure that your `itemType` is available in the `$parent` data.  You can do this by passing data to your template like:

`template: {name: 'list', data: { items: items, itemType: 'foo' } }`

So, rather than just passing `items`, now we pass `items` and `itemType`, so from one of the children `$parent.itemType` would contain "foo".

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/yeN8P/1/

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with option #2, that's exactly what I need. (Now that there is no value left to pass to `myBinding`, is there a convention what to use instead? `=data-bind"{myBinding: true}"`?)

Comment: You can pass `{}` or `true` or `''` to it.  No real convention.  Otherwise, you can remove your binding and wire it up outside.  If you want to make your binding more generic, then you could pass `listItemClickHandler` into it to decide what to hook up.

Comment: Could I just intercept the `template` binding's init function and get rid of my custom binding entirely?